# Modified Intel graphics driver(i915.ko), still old driver is loading on boot

Tags: graphics, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, intel, kernel-module

I have added some prints in my intel graphics driver (i915) code. And after building it, I replaced the default driver i915.ko in **/lib/modules/4.2.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/** with the new one. After system reboot I can see this driver is loaded properly but dmesg has no prints which I added in the driver code. It seems it is loading the old driver from somewhere else.
Here are some prints which I have added in the driver code to verify that the modified driver is loaded.

```
static int __init i915_init(void)
{
    printk("Inside i915_init ");
    driver.num_ioctls = i915_max_ioctl;

    printk("Inside i915_init ");
#if defined(CONFIG_DRM_I915_KMS)
    printk("Inside i915_init ");
    if (i915.modeset != 0)
        driver.driver_features |= DRIVER_MODESET;
    printk("Inside i915_init ");
#endif
    printk("Inside i915_init ");
    if (i915.modeset == 1)
        driver.driver_features |= DRIVER_MODESET;

    printk("Inside i915_init ");
#ifdef CONFIG_VGA_CONSOLE
    printk("Inside i915_init ");
    if (vgacon_text_force() && i915.modeset == -1)
        driver.driver_features &= ~DRIVER_MODESET;
#endif
    printk("Inside i915_init ");

    if (!(driver.driver_features & DRIVER_MODESET)) {
        driver.get_vblank_timestamp = NULL;
        /* Silently fail loading to not upset userspace. */
        DRM_DEBUG_DRIVER("KMS and UMS disabled.\n");
        return 0;
    }

    printk("Inside i915_init ");
    if (i915.nuclear_pageflip)
        driver.driver_features |= DRIVER_ATOMIC;

    printk("Inside i915_init ");
    return drm_pci_init(&driver, &i915_pci_driver);
}
```

Comment: `but dmesg has no prints which I added in the driver code.` - Messages **without terminated newline** appears in the log *with some delay* sometimes. It is better to specify newline: `printk("Inside i915_init\n");`

Comment: Tried putting the newline character but still no prints are coming

Comment: Even if I delete this kernel module i915.ko from /lib/modules/4.2.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/ system is loading it on boot. I am not able to figure out from where it is finding this module.

Comment: Linux kernel modules are usually loaded with [modprobe](https://linux.die.net/man/8/modprobe) utility. This utility checks configuration files [modprobe.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/modprobe.conf) and [depmod.conf](https://linux.die.net/man/5/depmod.conf). Search module name (`i915`) through these files: probably, the file at `/lib/modules/4.2.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko` is not used by `modprobe` at all.

Comment: /lib/modules/4.2.0-16-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko, This is the only location in my system where this module is located. Also there is no modprobe.conf and depmod.conf in my system. In stead /lib/linux-sound-base/noALSA.modprobe.conf and /lib/linux-sound-base/noOSS.modprobe.conf files are there.

Comment: `Also there is no modprobe.conf and depmod.conf in my system.` - These files **should** exists (without `depmod.conf` modprobe cannot resolve dependencies between modules). Probably, there are `modprobe.d` and `depmod.d` *directories* instead, as noted in the man. `This is the only location in my system where this module is located.` - it is possible that the driver is compiled into kernel, it is possible that it is blacklisted, or some other module is loaded instead. All these cases should be explicitely noted in `modprobe.conf`: that is why you need to find it.

Comment: I guess your older image had `i915` `built-in` as a part of `kernel` image. Now you have made it to build it as a `LKM` or your newer `.config`  is building it as a `LKM`. In any case, `clean` and build it again. Replace the `/boot/vmlinuz` with `arch/x86/boot/bzImage` as well. Then `#insmod /lib/modules/$(uname -r)/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko` and it should work!

Comment: I suspect you get the original driver from initrd. It's generally better to build and install the entire kernel and modules instead of replacing individual modules under `/lib/modules`.